# Do something after multiple async mongoose calls finishes

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose

I have a function that looks up data in several different documents, add some of the date from each document to a object and returns the object with the combines data from the different documents. The only problem is that the object is returned before any of the transactions are completed. I have googled a lot, and the only solution i can find is on Stack Overflow, but from 2012.... There must be some "newer" better way to do it? **Preferably without installing more npm stuff.**

Here is my function

```
function getPreviousEventCard(event, callback) {
    const card = {};
    card.dateStart = event.dateStart;
    card.dateEnd = event.dateEnd;
    card.userID = event.userID;
    card.adminID = event.adminID;

    // 1st async call
    Profile.getFullName(event.userID, (err, name) => {
        if (err) return callback(err, null);
        card.bsName = name.fullName;
    });

    // 2nd async call
    Profile.getProfileByUserId(event.parentID, (err, profile) => {
        if (err) return callback(err, null);
        card.parentName = profile.fullName;
        card.address = `${profile.address} ${profile.zip}`
    });

    // somehow wait until both(all) async calls are done and then:
    return callback(null, card);
}
```

btw, 'Profile' is a mongoose schema, and the get methods are using the findOne() method.

I have tried to nest the functions and have the return callback as the most inner, but then it is never returned for some reason.

Comment: What version of Node are you using?

Comment: Do `Profile.getFullName` return a Promise? If yes you should definitely use async await

Comment: What stuff on SO did you find and why do you think it isn't good enough?  Have you looked into `Promise.all()`?  I would expect `getFullName()` and `getProfileByUserId()` to return Promises.

Comment: Put your 2nd async call inside the callback of the 1st async call.  Then the 2nd async will not run until the 1st is complete.

Comment: Jeff, I dont think thats a good idea, then i will wait before starting the other aync call... it would be most efficient to start them at the same time since the DB is independent of the CPU where the calls are made.
@zero298 cant find it again... but it seemed outdated to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using NodeJS v8 or higher, I would [`promisify`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) those functions:

```
const getFullName = promisify(Profile.getFullName);
const getProfileByUserId = promisify(Profile.getProfileByUserId);
```

...and then use `Promise.all`:

```
function getPreviousEventCard(event, callback) {
    Promise.all([
        // 1st async call
        getFullName(event.userID),
        // 2nd async call
        getProfileByUserId(event.parentID)
     ])
    .then(([name, profile]) => {
        const card = {
            dateStart: event.dateStart,
            dateEnd: event.dateEnd,
            userID: event.userID,
            adminID: event.adminID,
            bsName: name.fullName,
            parentName: profile.fullName,
            address: `${profile.address} ${profile.zip}`;
        };
        callback(null, card);
    })
    .catch(err => callback(err);
}
```

or better yet, make `getPreviousEventCard` return a promise:

```
function getPreviousEventCard(event) {
    return Promise.all([
        // 1st async call
        getFullName(event.userID),
        // 2nd async call
        getProfileByUserId(event.parentID)
     ])
    .then(([name, profile]) => {
        return {
            dateStart: event.dateStart,
            dateEnd: event.dateEnd,
            userID: event.userID,
            adminID: event.adminID,
            bsName: name.fullName,
            parentName: profile.fullName,
            address: `${profile.address} ${profile.zip}`;
        };
    });
}
```

---

> Preferably without installing more `npm` stuff

If you *did* want to install more `npm` stuff, there's an `npm` module that will promisify an entire API (rather than function by function) using a declarative description of the APIs functions: https://www.npmjs.com/package/promisify

Comment: @RasmusPuls: Yes, the link in the first sentence is to the Node docs. It was added in v8.

Comment: This looks very useful! Thanks, I will look into this.

Comment: @RasmusPuls: No worries. FYI, I added some missing parentheses to the above (I forgot to put them around the destructured parameters `[name, profile]`), so the literal code would have had a syntax error. (You'd've figured it out, but...)